# Javascript Regex validate input year between 1945 - current year

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate my input text with input year from 1945 until current year with using regex.. but I still don't have any idea how to get dynamic year.. I saw many reference from stackoverflow but they only do it for static year like 1945 - 2000.

I want to make it dynamic like user only can input 1945 until 2018(current year), if user input 2019, it will display an error

This is static:

```
let yearPattern = new RegExp(/^(194[5-9]|19[5-9]\d|200\d|2018)$/)
```

I have tried to trick it but I think the validation won't work

I tried like this:

```
let currentYear = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY').split('')
let yearPattern = new RegExp(/^(1769|17[7-9]\d|18\d\d|19\d\d|200\d|current)$/)
let valid = yearPattern.replace("current", `[2-${currentYear[0]}][0-${currentYear[1]}][0-${currentYear[2]}][0-${currentYear[3]}]`
```

At the end of using this, my validation won't work..

Comment: Just use a Date object and compare years? Why use a RegEx?

Comment: I am using react js and antd design framework...It has pattern that using regex..

Comment: You are doing exactly what [this site](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) does. I suggest you to get in touch with the author or get inspired with the minified code there.

Comment: I have tried it too.. but as I said before, it's static.. if tomorrow is 2019, so  I have to change my regex pattern..

Comment: @James, since you really do need a dynamic regex I took another swipe at it.  See if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a String value when creating a new RegEx.  Just omit the forward slashes.

**UPDATE:** Restored my answer with what I think is a working solution and regex.

```js
function getPattern(dt) {
  let y = moment(dt).format('YYYY').split('');
  let patternStr = `^(194[5-9]|19[5-9]\\d|20[0-${y[2]-1}]\\d|20${y[2]}[0-${y[3]}])$`;
  return new RegExp(patternStr);
}

let pattern = getPattern(new Date());
console.log(pattern.test('1944')); // false
console.log(pattern.test('1945')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('1975')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2000')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2002')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2010')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2011')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2018')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2019')); // false

console.log('***');

pattern = getPattern('2023-01-01');
console.log(pattern.test('2018')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2019')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2020')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2021')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2022')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2023')); // true
console.log(pattern.test('2024')); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: What about 2011 to 2017?

Comment: OK, since James indicated that he indeed needed a regex I sorted through a working regex with the necessary dynamic substitution.  I'm still learning on the regex front, so if there is a problem with this formulation let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: your code is not 100%work... because I think that the pattern of the regex is still 50% dynamic.. because it only valid until 2099.. am I right?

Comment: That's true James, but how far out do you really need it to go?  It's confusing enough to read as it is.  Keeping at least moderately readable seems like a reasonable consideration to me.  You wanted a solution in which you could dynamically substitute regex values for the current year.  This solution will work for the next almost 82 years.  My opinion though.  If you want it 100% dynamic then this gives you a place to start.

Comment: without moment.js
let y = new Date().getFullYear().toString().split('').map(Number);

Answer (score 2):

Why using `RegEx` and not simply check if `date` isn't smaller than *1945* or bigger than *current year*?

Using a `RegEx` for such a simple task make things rather complicated. Instead go for a simpler solution.

**Like so**

```js
var input = "2011";
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

if(input < 1945 == false && input > currentYear == false)
{
  // Correct input data given, its not smaller than 1945 or bigger than current year
  console.log(true);
}
else
{
  // Date is either smaller than 1945 or bigger than current year, return false.
  console.log(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```js
let currentYear = moment().year().toString();

let first = currentYear.substring(2, 3);
let second = currentYear.substring(3, 4);

let yearPattern = new RegExp(`^(194[5-9]|19[5-9][0-9]|20[0-${first}][0-${second}])$`);

console.log(yearPattern.test('1944')); // false
console.log(yearPattern.test('1945')); // true
console.log(yearPattern.test('2008')); // true
console.log(yearPattern.test('2011')); // true
console.log(yearPattern.test('2017')); // true
console.log(yearPattern.test('2019')); // false
console.log(yearPattern.test('2099')); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** : This will work upto 2099. I think it is sufficient for you. Right? If you want to go beyond 2099 then follow what I did and you are good to go.

Comment: I'm obviously no pro with regex, but won't this break once we reach 2020?  In 2020 this regex would no longer validate 2019 if I'm reading it right.  The first substitution would work, but the second substitution wouldn't.  Am I missing something?  I re-posted below with a solution that I think covers what James is looking for.

Comment: is it possible to make 100% dynamic using regex? because this is only valid until 2099